# Formatting JSON from a Pandas data frame for Highcharts within a Django template

Tags: python, json, django, pandas, highcharts

I have a Pandas data frame that I have converted to JSON like so:

```
json_data = data_df.to_json()
```

The original data frame looks like something similar to this:

```
    col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1     2     2    -1
1     2     4     3    -2
2     3     6     4    -3
3     4     8     5    -4
4     5     10    6    -5
...
```

And the JSON string looks similar to this:

```
[{"col1":1,"col2":2,"col3":2,"col4":-1},{"col1":2,"col2":4,"col3":3,"col4":-2},{"col1":3,"col2":6,"col3":4,"col4":-3},{"col1":4,"col2":8,"col3":5,"col4":-4}]
```

My `Highcharts` implementation is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var my_data = '{{ json_data }}'
            
    // create data chart
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'chart_panel',
            type: 'line',
        },
        legend: {layout: 'vertical',
                 align: 'right',
                 verticalAlign: 'middle',
                 borderWidth: 0,
        },
        title: {text: 'Roehrig Damper Data',
                x: -20 // center title
        },
        xAxis: {title: {text: 'Velocity (m/sec)'}},
        yAxis: {title: {text: 'Force (N)'}},
        series: [ {data: my_data} ],
    });

});
```

The `{{ json_data }}` is from my Django python view and I have confirmed that it's properly formatted through the browser console. Currently my code is only displaying a blank `Highcharts` chart with zero data being populated. I have tried a few different ways to manipulate the data that I desire, but without success.

My goal is to plot `col2` against `col1` and on the same chart plot `col4` against `col3`, or in other words the x-axis will be defined by both `col1` and `col3`.

Is there a way to accomplish my goal stated above, and if so, how?

## Edit

With the help of @Andrew_Lvov I now have a JSON object that looks like this:

```
json_data = [
    {
        'name': "col1",
        'data': array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])},
    {
        'name': "col2",
        'data': array([2, 4, 6, 8, 10])},
    // etc.
]
```

Now my problem is that it is adding the word `array` to the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var myData = {{ json_data | safe }};
```

**UPDATE**:

Your data should be in format:

```
json_data = [
    {
        'name': "col1",
        'data': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]},
    {
        'name': "col2",
        'data': [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]},
]
```

Series parameter:

```
        series: myData
```

**UPDATE #2:**

```
json_data = [{'data': list(value.values), 'name': key} for key, value in data_df.items()]
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense, but how can I get my `json_data` to resemble the format you provided? I've changed it around some using an argument in `pandas.to_json(orient='records')`. See edit for current JSON format.

Comment: @aus_lacy Updated. Don't forget to convert json_data to json:
json.dumps(json_data)

Comment: Your snippet is very close to working except that it is also including the index in the `data` column. Is there a way to drop or ignore the index column?

Comment: @aus_lacy, sorry, didn't notice.
    [{'name': key, 'data': list(value.values())} for key, value in data_df.items()]

Comment: It's giving me this error `'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable`.

Comment: What's the data in data_df ?

Comment: The data looks like something very similar to the data frame that I included in the original question only with different numerical values and column header names.

Comment: Then I can only guess. Try value.values instead of value.values()

Comment: That removed the error. See my above edit for update on JSON object. Ignore edit to question. I fixed it by rearranging it to `json_data = [{'data': value.values, 'name': key} for key, value in data_df.items()]`.

Comment: It doesn't work because of the word `array` that is appended in front of the list of data items.

Comment: I can help you with TeamViewer session if you care

Comment: Ahh I only had `value.values` rather than `list(value.values)`. That got rid of the `array`. I still need to check with construction of the highcharts plot. Thanks for all the help though!

Comment: Thanks to you I was able to get it working. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you happen to have any ideas on how to plot 2 series onto the same chart as I explained in the original question? Like plotting `col2` against `col1` and `col4` against `col3`. I'm struggling to figure out how I can only access only certain parts of the `JSON` under the `series:` parameter.

Comment: No worries. I'll make a separate question. Thanks again.